# apt-get update and apt-get upgrade in Chef

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant, apt-get

If `package "nginx"` in Chef gets translated into `apt-get install nginx` on an Ubuntu node, what can be written in a Chef recipe that would translate into:

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

Couldn't figure out from the [`apt` cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt).

Comment: Would this https://github.com/patdeegan/chef-unattended-upgrades help?

Comment: I think so, but I'm interested if there is any lighter solution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[The Opscode "apt" cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt)'s default recipe will run `apt-get update` to ensure that the package cache is updated. We recommend putting that early in your node's run list so later on packages can be installed with the correct versions.

We generally don't recommend that users use "`apt-get upgrade`" in a recipe, for a couple reasons.

1. `apt-get` may upgrade a package that has conflicting configuration or other issues that cannot be resolved without running the command again, or running other apt/dpkg commands manually.
2. Automated upgrades of all packages on the system can have unintended side effects on the running system (the edge cases are many and possibly thorny, so I can't cover them all).

Instead, use the "upgrade" action for packages that should always update to the latest version.

```
package "nginx" do
  action :upgrade
end
```

If you're reusing a cookbook that defines the cookbook, you can write a recipe that modifies the action of the existing resource, like this:

```
resources("package[nginx]").action(:upgrade)
```

The `#resources` method in a recipe will look up in the Resource Collection the specified resource (package nginx). Then sending the `#action` method with the argument `:upgrade` will tell Chef that the action should be to upgrade.

*Edit* **Update**: Do be careful when choosing packages that would be upgraded automatically in this way. An upstream change in a package can cause detrimental effects on the system. This is especially true if such a package does a restart of services it manages during the post installation scripts. Know your infrastructure, and if in doubt run your own package repository that has the critical packages you need for the application stack.

Comment: everybody says this, yet I cannot get the repository list to update when I include the apt cookbook and call it's default recipe. Worse yet, if another recipe incorporated into one of mine is dependent on apt, then there seems to be no possible way short of manually updating by logging into the node. I wish there was a definitive explanation somewhere as to how to get the apt-get repository to update in situations where you're forced to use the apt cookbook.

Comment: It appears that apt will only update every 24 hours. This temp file controls the process. /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp

Answer (score 0):

The Apt chef recipe will not update with every chef run. The attribute which controls this is called `periodic_update_min_delay` and is set to 86400 (The attribute should be called sec_delay). If the following file exists and is older than 24 hours apt will update the cache.

```
/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
```

It also appears that the apt recipe (default.rb) includes a directive to force an update which your recipe could call.

```
# For other recipes to call to force an update
execute 'apt-get update' do
```

If you're doing that though, you'll want a not_if to avoid running it too often at which point you might as well call it manually yourself. I got sick of messing with this and ended up just calling apt-get update in a stanza before my install.

```
execute "apt-get-update" do
  command "apt-get update"
end
```

I suspect the long-term solution for security updates is to set update delay to a few hours.